# Fetching IAP localized price in Unity

Tags: unity

How can I obtain localized price of products to show on my purchase page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Unity's IAP solution, `ProductMetadata.localizedPriceString` will give you localized price of an in-app product.
`ProductMetadata` has other properties as well, including localized title & description.

[ProductMetadata documentation](https://docs.unity.cn/Packages/com.unity.purchasing@3.1/api/UnityEngine.Purchasing.ProductMetadata.html)